# Comparison between pointer and integer warning

Tags: c

When I attempt to compare a pointer array (which initially is NULL) and char pointer:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){   

    char **list = (char**)malloc(20*sizeof(char)+1);
    char *input = "La li lu le lo";


    if(*list[0] != input[0]) { //or if(list[0][0]!=input[0])
        printf("false: %s", strdict[0]);
    }
}
```

I constantly get a warning:

> comparison between pointer and integer

What must be done to remove this warning?
If I modify it to be:

```
if(*list[0] != input[0])
```

the warning is removed, yet the program crashes.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: define "fails to run". It does not compile? It crashes? It says "False: ..."?

Comment: Well, 1) remove malloc `cast` and close the `(`. 2) you are comparing `char*` list[0] and `char` input[0]. Isn't valid in C; you need to do `list[0][0] != input[0]` 3) `list` is uninitialised

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't compile. Missing ";" and a brace that shouldn't be there :P

Comment: It might help to add some information about what you are hoping to accomplish with the program.  For example, are you trying to see if the first string in a list is equal to another string?  There are some logic issues with the code that make it difficult to determine what the intent is.

Comment: not sure who approved that edit, but please don't correct/change the OPs code, that's what answers are for.

Answer (score 5):

The type of `input[0]` is a `char` whereas the type of `list[0]` is a `char*`. If you wish to compare strings use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

*However*, the `malloc()` is incorrect and the `list` content is uninitialised. I *think*, based on its name and type, `list` is intended to be a list of `char*`:

```
/* No need to cast return value of malloc(). */
char **list = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));
```

Then each element is `char*` and needs set to some `char*`, possibly `malloc()`d also:

```
list[0] = malloc(20); 
/* Populate list[0] with some characters. */

/* Compare to input. */
if (0 == strcmp(list[0], input))
{
    /* Strings equal. */
}
```

Comment: If only I could cast another upvote for mentioning that malloc() doesn't need a cast

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are comparing an integer to an array, since List has two stars before it. Input[0] is a char whereas List[0] is an array, if you looked at List[0][0] then you would be comparing two equivalent objects.